# How to read only specific fields of a nested JSON file in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file with 100k lines and I want to read the JSON file into pandas dataframe. Now, the JSON file has nested structure for each line. For example (A file with two lines):

```
{
    "A": "sample1_A",
    "B": "sample1_B",
    "Metadata": {
        "Data": {
            "C": {
                "C_1": "sample1_C1",
                "C_2": "sample1_C2",
                "C_3": "sample1_C3"
            }
        }
    },
    "D": "sample1_D",
}
{
    "A": "sample2_A",
    "B": "sample2_B",
    "Metadata": {
        "Data": {
            "C": {
                "C_1": "sample2_C1",
                "C_2": "sample2_C2",
                "C_3": "sample2_C3"
            }
        }
    },
    "D": "sample2_D",
}
```

I want to read only **A** and **MetaData.Data.C.C_2** fields of each line into the dataframe. The output in the dataframe should be like below:

[image]

Right now, I tried with read_json method of pandas like below:

[image]

How can I read only specific fields of nested JSON in pandas?

Comment: Why don't you just preprocess the JSON to produce exactly the structure you want, then import it into pandas?  That's a lot more efficient than importing everything and mashing up the dataframe.

Comment: That's can be one way. I was thinking if there is any way to directly load into pandas dataframe without preprocessing. Also I have observed preprocessing each line take a lot of time.

Comment: Pandas is a large, powerful, and slow module.  In my experience, anything you can do in Python code to reduce the burden on pandas is a net gain.